# Freemarker CSV generation - CSV with Chinese text truncates the csv contents

Tags: csv, java-8, freemarker, cjk, truncated

I have this very weird problem. I'm using Java 8, Struts2 and Freemarker 2.3.23 to generate reports in csv and html file formats (via.csv.ftl and .html.ftl templates both saved in utf-8 encoding), with data coming from postgres database.
The data has chinese characters in it and when I generate the report in html format, it is fine and complete and chinese characters are displayed properly. But when the report is generated in csv, I have observed that:

1. If I run the app **with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 VM option**, the chinese characters are generated properly but the report is incomplete (i.e. the texts are truncated specifically on the near end part)
2. If I run the app **without -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 VM option**, the chinese characters are displayed in question marks (?????) but the report is complete

Also, the app uses **StringWriter** to write the data to the csv and html templates.

So, what could be the problem? Am I hitting Java character limits? I do not see error in the logs either. Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The **StringWriter** returns the data in whole, however when writing the data to the **OutputStream**, this is where some of the data gets lost.

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Looks like the issue is on `contentLength` (because the app is a webapp and csv is generated as file-download type) being generated from the data as Strings using String.length(). The String.length() method returns less value when there should be more. Maybe it has something to do with the chinese characters that's why length is being reported with less value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with `contentLength` by using String.getBytes("UTF-8").length

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)